# вероятно, неправильно отображается причина тревоги в профиле

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, тревоги

я отметил «тревогой» как спам (первый пункт в диалоге «тревога») [*вот этот «вопрос»*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/440300/178576).

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

а на соответствующей странице профиля (`https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/flag-summary/178576`) про эту «тревогу» написано: «отмечены как оскорбление» (см. картинку).

> [image: из профиля]

то ли я не понимаю тонкостей работы системы «тревог», то ли причина указана неправильно (к тому же с ошибкой: вместо «отмечен**ы**» правильнее было бы  «отмечен»).

Comment: [Подтверждаю, у меня то же самое воспроизводится](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bKyOj.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На сколько я могу судить, это ошибка перевода. Строка

> flagged as $startSpan$spam$stopSpan$

Была переведена как:

> отмечены как $startSpan$ оскорбление$stopSpan$

Поправил на:

> отмечен как $startSpan$спам$stopSpan$

Перевод будет доступен в ближайшей сборки сайта.

Comment: Забастовка переменных: `$stopSpam!` `$stopSpam!`